# Oracle statement sometimes doesn't return any data without error message

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query below generated by a BI tool that is executed on Oracle version 12.2. Sometimes one, few, or all columns in the results are empty, no error message is returned. In most of the cases the output is complete though. This happens both in the BI tool and when executing the query against the database directly using Oracle SQL Developer 19.

After playing with the BI tool settings I suspect that the problem might be related to the usage of global temp tables or parallel execution or both in combination.

Here is the query, I had to remove table and column names.

```
ALTER SESSION SET PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY=AUTO;

create GLOBAL TEMPORARY table ZZMD00 ()
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS

insert into ZZMD00
select /*+ NO_STATEMENT_QUEUING */
commit

ANALYZE TABLE ZZMD00 ESTIMATE STATISTICS SAMPLE 25 PERCENT

create GLOBAL TEMPORARY table ZZMD01 ()
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS

insert into ZZMD01
select /*+ NO_STATEMENT_QUEUING */
commit

ANALYZE TABLE ZZMD01 ESTIMATE STATISTICS SAMPLE 25 PERCENT

create GLOBAL TEMPORARY table ZZMD02 ()
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS

insert into ZZMD02
select /*+ NO_STATEMENT_QUEUING */
commit

ANALYZE TABLE ZZMD02 ESTIMATE STATISTICS SAMPLE 25 PERCENT

create GLOBAL TEMPORARY table ZZMD03 ()
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS

insert into ZZMD03
select /*+ NO_STATEMENT_QUEUING */
commit

ANALYZE TABLE ZZMD03 ESTIMATE STATISTICS SAMPLE 25 PERCENT

select /*+ NO_STATEMENT_QUEUING */
from ZZMD00 pa11
full outer join ZZMD01 pa12
   on  ()
full outer join ZZMD02 pa13
   on  ()
full outer join ZZMD03 pa14
   on  ()

ALTER SESSION SET PARALLEL_DEGREE_POLICY=MANUAL
```

Does anyone know what can cause the incomplete or empty results here?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Some emtpy columns in a full outer join usually indicate that the join condition is not satisfied. Are you sure that the join works as expected?

Comment: Hi Erich, I think you are right and at the end the problem is related to one or multiple temp tables being empty. What is not clear is why. Data-wise all columns should contain non-empty results which is also the case in 9 out of 10 executions.

Comment: Without any details about those temp tables, it will be difficult to help you any further. One last hint: Maybe they are not empty, but the keys do not match, so the join fails.

Comment: There's not much we can except guess until you provide some table structures and sample data which reproduces the problem.

Comment: By the way, not related to the problem but [`analyze`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4005.htm) has been deprecated for several releases in favour of [`dbms_stats`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm).